# Installing video drivers fails and causes video to completely fail, only solution is to reformat and reinstall Windows

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card

I've recently upgraded my PC and using my old pc as a secondary, but there's a problem.

When I install Windows (XP Pro) and update it, everything is working fine. I even install chipset drivers, audio drivers, etc and it all works.

However, when I install the nVidia drivers for the GeForce 8400 I just bought, the installation 'fails to install the nVidia control panel, reverting back to the last known working driver'. Once this completes, a reboot is required. After reboot, the bios screen shows, the Windows loading screen shows, then nothing. All black.

I can verify this also happens with an ATI card from a fresh reinstall, too.

The motherboard is most definitely good, as the day before I swapped, I was using my 9800GTX in it with no problems. The only changes to this fully working machine were the video card, hard drive, and version of Windows.

This Windows XP Pro disc is from 2002 and requires a lot of updates to get it running. Could this be the problem? Would another version of Windows work?

What else could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that the LCD monitor was bad. It would not accept any resolution over 640x480, causing a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the Win-Version. Get or Create a new version (with SP3 and latest patches) and try it with that one. *But* if the issue is independently from the manufacturer of the graphiccard (as you suggested), it's a problem with the motherboard.

Comment: Well, that motherboard worked before the swap with another card, and both an ATI and nVidia card failed.